# How to call a controller method from Javascript

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am displaying a bunch of movies in a table, I am eventually deleting each movie through Javascript which hides the div.

I now want to delete the movie from the database as well, so what is the best way to call the controller method from the Javascript?

Comment: Lots of ways.  You could build a form with the data and post it, you could follow a GET link in the proper format, you could invoke an AJAX call... your question is not specific enough

Comment: submitting a POST or DELETE with AJAX is the way to go. destructive actions like deletes shouldn't be done with a GET

Comment: Can you show your controller method and how/where you are populating the movie id you'd like to delete in your javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have an **HTTPPost** action method to delete in your `movie` controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
  try
  {
    repo.DeleteMovie(id);
    return "deleted"
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    //Log errror
  }
  return "failed";
}
```

And in your View,

```
<a href="#" data-movieId="34" class="movie">Delete Avengers</a>
<a href="#" data-movieId="35" class="movie">Delete Iron Man</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

   $(".movie").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $.post("@Url.Action("Delete","Movie")", { id : $(this).data("movieId")} ,function(data){
        alert(data);
     });
   });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your code it could be as simple as:

```
$.post("/controller/method/" + id);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try this: (Using jQuery Ajax)**

```
$("#DeleteButtonID").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        page: 1,
        rp: 6,
        url: '@Url.Action("PopulateDataListWithHeader", "DataList")' + "?id=" + YOURID,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {

        },
        error: function(x, e) {

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
function (){
   var url = '@Url.Action("SearchReoccurence", "SearchReoccurence", new { errormessage = "__msg__" })';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for the party, but maybe it will help someone.
For me, on ASP.NET MVC 5 this work wonderfully:

#### Client jQuery side

```
let data1 = 'some text';
let data2 = 'some other text';

$.post('ControllerName/MethodName', { field1: data1, field2: data2 }, 
    function(response) {
    // Do something here with the data return from the controller
    }
});
```

`field1` and `field2` needed to be the exact same name written in your method fields.

It's best to user `JsonResult` as the return type from your controller's method and parse it with `Json()` method.

#### Controller's method example

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Method(string field1, string field2)
{
    // Do something here with the data sent from the jQuery client side
    ClassExample example = new();
    return Json(example);
}
```