# Call a class in javascript in visual studio

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller class that I get data from database and return it in a function, Now I want to call this function in a js and set the data in variables to show in a page:

My code looks like: exampleController.cs

```
namespace iSee.WebApiHse.Controllers
{
    public class expController : StandardController
    {

        public expController(
            first myService,
            ISystemSettings systemSettings,
            IService myExpService)
        {
            _myService = MyService;
            _systemSettings = systemSettings;
            _myExpService = myExpService;
        }

        // GET data
        public ActionResult Myexample(int id)
        {
            var elementIds = _systemSettings.ExpIds; 

            var myElements = CacheService.AllVisibleElements
                                  .Where(x => elementIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();

            var container = _kpiContainerService.Find(id);

            var result = _myService.MonthByContainer(myElements, container);
            return AsJson(result);
        }
    }
}
```

This works and I get the data. Now I have `myExp.js` that I need to use these data in it. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute `$ajax(..)` (jquery syntax) request to your controller to pass and get compute information from the server.

For this your controller method, that you're going to call, has to be exposed for HTTP access.

More details on :

[How to call controller method from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949937/how-to-call-controller-method-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want work with your controller in View by JavaScript? It isn't good idea. You should pass Model to View and work with it or  ajax and recieve json-data

Answer (score 0):

An example that uses [jQuery-ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to call your C# method:

```
// javascript

var id = 987;

$.ajax({
    url : '/expController/Myexample/',
    type : 'GET',
    data { id : id },
    dataType : 'json', // <-- tell jQuery to decode the JSON automatically
    success : function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

This would call your method, passing in the value of `id`, then it would decode the JSON into the `response` object.

For plain Javascript ajax (no jQuery) see [MDN Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a request to the Action `Myexample`.  Usually this is done via `AJAX`:

In your view you could have:

```
function makeAJaxCall(idToSend) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("exp", "Myexample")',
        data: { id : idToSend },
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
           $("#HTMLElement").val(data.YourData);
        }
    });
}
```

Your response will come back in the `data` variable if the `AJAX` call succeeds. I have provided an example to show you how to change the value of an HTML element with the `ID` HTMLElement.

To invoke the function you can do:

```
 makeAjaxCall(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may load the JSON data in a `var` and pass it to the function in `expjs.js`, as:

```
var data = data_from_ajax();
exp_js_function(data);
```

`data_from_ajax()` would receive JSON data from your controller and action method.

> Please consider this as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution